# matlab contour with many colors

Tags: matlab, contour

```
contour( matrix,'LineColor','k');
```

Then I got the above graph. I know the reason for this is because the difference of the values in this matrix is not so large. So how to make the graph more 'colorful'?

PS: I just found out that I cannot post an image. Just imagine the case when: matrix=[1,2,3; 2,3,5]

Comment: You can post the image as link to i.e. http://imgur.com and someone with enough rep will add it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
contourf( matrix,'LineColor','k');
```